# How to do a case-insensitive query for sqlalchemy association_proxy attributes?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two classes, a Track and an Album. In order to have album fields easily accessible from a track, I created an [association proxy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#).

```py
class Track(MusicItem, Base):
    __tablename__ = "tracks"

    _id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    _album_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("albums._id"))
    artist = Column(String, nullable=False, default="")
    path = Column(_PathType, nullable=False, unique=True)
    title = Column(String, nullable=False, default="")

    _album_obj = relationship("Album", back_populates="tracks")

    album = association_proxy('_album_obj', 'title')
```

```py
class Album(MusicItem, Base):
    __tablename__ = "albums"

    _id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    artist = Column(String, nullable=False, default="")
    title = Column(String, nullable=False, default="")

    tracks = relationship("Track", back_populates="_album_obj", cascade="all, delete")
```

However, I am having issues when trying to do a case-insensitive query for track or album.

When creating a query filter, the following works fine for normal (non-association proxy) attributes of a Track.

```py
attr = getattr(Track, field)
attr = sqlalchemy.func.lower(attr)
```

But, when `attr` is an association proxy attribute, the following error occurs:

```py
moe/core/query.py:187: in query
    items = session.query(query_cls).filter(*query_filters).all()
.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:3346: in all
    return list(self)
.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:3508: in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:3533: in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1011: in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:298: in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1124: in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1316: in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1510: in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py:182: in raise_
    raise exception
.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1276: in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.pysqlite.SQLiteDialect_pysqlite object at 0x7f54a0692430>
cursor = <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f54a0638b90>
statement = 'SELECT tracks._id AS tracks__id, tracks._album_id AS tracks__album_id, tracks.artist AS tracks_artist, tracks.path AS tracks_path, tracks.title AS tracks_title \nFROM tracks \nWHERE lower(?) = ?'
parameters = (ColumnAssociationProxyInstance(AssociationProxy('_album_obj', 'title')), 'tmp')
context = <sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.base.SQLiteExecutionContext object at 0x7f54a05b7fa0>

    def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
>       cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
E       sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
E       [SQL: SELECT tracks._id AS tracks__id, tracks._album_id AS tracks__album_id, tracks.artist AS tracks_artist, tracks.path AS tracks_path, tracks.title AS tracks_title 
E       FROM tracks 
E       WHERE lower(?) = ?]
E       [parameters: (ColumnAssociationProxyInstance(AssociationProxy('_album_obj', 'title')), 'tmp')]
E       (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/rvf5)

.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:593: InterfaceError
```

Not sure if helpful, but here's some more simplified code on the query. I can expand on this if needed.

```py
query_filters = [attr == query_value]
items = session.query(Track).filter(*query_filters).all()
```

I have also seen [this relevant piece in the docs on creating a custom comparator](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy.ColumnAssociationProxyInstance.operate), but I could not figure out how to apply this to my code. I added it alongside the Track/Album classes, but it did not help anything and the same error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of version 1.3.19, sqlalchemy doesn't allow applying SQL functions to association proxy attributes. [Here is an issue that tracks that](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5541).

For the specific case of doing a case-insensitive lookup, you can use [`ilike()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy.ColumnAssociationProxyInstance.ilike)

```py
session.query(Track).filter(somecolumn.ilike("value"))
```

`ilike()` works for both association proxy attributes and normal attributes.